# Infusing orange into tea while avoiding bitterness

Tags: tea, infusion

What precautions should I follow to avoid imparting a bitter taste when infusing orange into my tea by placing the rind in the teapot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to remove as much of the pith as possible before drying peels or using them fresh.  You can use a microplane or zester to remove rind without cutting into the pith.

You can remove even more bitterness if you boil the rinds for one minute, drain, add fresh water and repeat.  Do this several times.

Comment: I found an ice cream scoop to be an effective depither. Thanks for the idea.